# Why do I get an authentication error with SMTP?

Tags: python, google-api, google-sheets-api

Every time I run this program, it runs the first time, but the second time it gives this error in terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 30, in <module>
    timenow = datetime.now()
  File "main.py", line 27, in temperature
    moApparent = regexApparentTemp.search(str(json_object))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/models.py", line 888, in append_row
    return self.spreadsheet.values_append(self.title, params, body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/models.py", line 119, in values_append
    r = self.client.request('post', url, params=params, json=body)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gspread/client.py", line 79, in request
    raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

The code is:

```
import requests, pprint, re, gspread, time
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from datetime import datetime



def temperature():
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    from datetime import datetime
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Singapore-Weather-84def2be176a.json', scope)

    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    wks = gc.open('Singapore Weather').sheet1
    r = requests.get('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/b02b5107a2c9c27deaa3bc1876bcee81/1.312914,%20103.780257')
    json_object = r.text


    regexCurrentTemp = re.compile(r'"temperature":(\d\d.\d\d)')
    moTemp = regexCurrentTemp.search(str(json_object))
    temperature = moTemp.group(1)

    regexApparentTemp = re.compile(r'"apparentTemperature":(\d\d.\d\d)')
    moApparent = regexApparentTemp.search(str(json_object))
    apparent = moApparent.group(1)

    timenow = datetime.now()
    wks.append_row([str(timenow), temperature, apparent])

while True:
    temperature()
    time.sleep(3597)
```

I put the autentication within the function in the loop so it would work, but it didn't. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't see SMTP in your code (Send Mail Transfer Protocol). If you get error then first use `print()` to check what you have in variables. Maybe you send wrong values.

Comment: BTW: darksky sends data as JSON so you don't have to conver to string and use regex but `apparent = r.json()['currently']['apparentTemperature']` and `temperature = r.json()['currently']['temperature']`

Comment: Why did I put SMTP???

Comment: Anyways, it works the first time, but then I get an authentication error

Comment: maybe you should make authorization only once - before `while True`.

Comment: I tried that, and I thought the problem was because it was in a different hour I was making the authentication call

Comment: Or maybe you have to get new credential after connection and save it to use it next time. Usually authorization change some values every few minuts or hours - for security.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that. In the tutorial vid I saw, I thought the JSON file was all you needed. It is annoying that it works once then gets an error.

Comment: do you have problem when you use shorter time ? I tested with `sleep(3)` and it worked. Do you use this sheet at the same time with other program?

Comment: It works with 30, but that is just too much.

Comment: i don't know what is the problem but you can still use `30` to check redential but skip requests and add to sheet only every 1 hour.

Comment: The problem is adding to the sheet. Maybe I could use it so that it does a redundant command with the google API

Comment: I would start with this and swap out the analytics stuff for google sheets the code should be close.  Your using a service account it should just work. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-py

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [Github googleapis/**oauth2client**](https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client) is **deprecated**

I would suggest you to try official [Gmail API Python example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending):

```py
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEText(message_text)
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject
  return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string(
))}
```

If you struggle with an example above try the [Gmail API Quickstart Python tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

Comment: This isn't an answer. I am not looking to send an email, I am looking to do a google sheets. This should be a comment as a suggestion, not an answer. The question is "Why do I get an authentication error with SMTP?". I didn't mean to say SMTP, so I apologize. But, if you read the first three lines of my code you would see that I didn't use SMTP at all.